# Waterline query where clause with 2 "or" clauses

Tags: sails.js, waterline, sails-mongo

I am trying to write a sails waterline query with two 'or' clauses where both have to be true, but it seems to not work. This is the query that I have tried but it pulls only when one of the 'or' clauses meets its criteria, which I am trying to return only when both 'or' clauses' criteria are met, not one. Is this a bug or is there another way to do this?

```
Employee.find()
.where({
  or: [
    {locationId: employee.currentLocation.id},
    {facilityId: employee.facilityId, userName:employee.userName,accountOwner: true}
]})
.where({
  or:[
    {employeeId: { startsWith: params.search.value }},
    {fullName: { startsWith: params.search.value }},
    {street: { startsWith: params.search.value }},                              
    {emailAddress: { startsWith: params.search.value }},
    {employeeType: { startsWith: params.search.value }},
    {status: { startsWith: params.search.value }}
]});
```

Comment: That's how an OR [works](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_algebra#Basic_operations).

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the mongo adapter, you can do the following to AND two OR statements together:

```
Employee.find().where({
  $and: [{
    or: [{
      locationId: employee.currentLocation.id
    }, {
      facilityId: employee.facilityId,
      userName: employee.userName,
      accountOwner: true,
    }],
  }, {
    or:[{
      employeeId: { startsWith: params.search.value }
    }, {
      fullName: { startsWith: params.search.value }
    }, {
      street: { startsWith: params.search.value }
    }, {
      emailAddress: { startsWith: params.search.value }
    }, {
      employeeType: { startsWith: params.search.value }
    }, {
      status: { startsWith: params.search.value }
    }],
  }],
});
```